# Precompile JST templates in strict mode in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs, jst

I try to compile jst.js with BabelJS, but I faced with the next error:

```
  Aborted due to warnings.
  Running "babel:dev" (babel) task
  Warning: .tmp/public/jst.js: 'with' in strict mode (3:113)
```

How can I precompile templates in strict mode?